# Expose port to EC2 instance of another machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I want to expose port of a EC2 machine(us-west-2b) to access from another machine(us-west-2a). For that, I have created a security group with CIDR range.

check the below image :
[image]

But it is not opening the port. What is the right way of achieving this without making port public

I have created a security group and added that security group to two machines. For each machine, i have exposed 9001 port to the newly created security group. Now i tried accessing port of one machine from another machine But it is not working.

[image]

Comment: Are both machines in the same subnet or VPC? In short, is there a route between the machines?

Comment: both machines in the same VPC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different security groups, one per EC2 instance.

then edit that one  you want to open the PORT and add as a source the other security group.

Check this example ... I am opening port 3306 only for SG: sg-xxxx

[image]

then use the private IP address and NOT the public IP.

Comment: again, use 2 different security groups ... why you want to use the same one ?